# Sporadic error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to debug an issue on a clients system.

We use ASP.NET 2.0 webforms in VB.NET and SQL Server 2005. When loading a certain page clients are reporting errors saying value "index" is out of bounds. I am yet to see this (and nobody has screenshot the issue), but I just get no data returning on the page instead of an issue show up.

BUT: Our issue audit logging system is storing error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server.

The error is quite sporadic, sometimes everything works fine, and then within half an hour you can get the issue 2-3 times after it tries to load and timeout after about 5minutes.

I don't really have permission to show compiled code, but the code is used for many other clients without an issue.

The connection string is like this:

```
<add name="****" 
     connectionString="Server=***\SQL2005;Database=032;User Id=*******;Pwd=*****;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I am wondering, could I be getting the error: 40 because of a network issue, or should I be looking deeper into the code e.g parameter values passed.

I am quite confused, has anyone else seen something like this?

Comment: If the code compiles without any errors and you can connect successfully sometime and sometimes you are having issues, it is more likely to be a network error, as if it were a code issue or connection string issue, it will never be compiled and never let you connect to the server.

Comment: Not neccessarily, if it was a runtime error it would still compile. The fact that there has been a reported system error (although I have been unable to reproduce it) has me confused. Could a coding runtime mistake be jamming the connection to the database and causing it to timeout and create error 40?

Comment: Do you have a load balanced setup?